# Show $z^n=\exp(nf(z))$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f$ a branch of the logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Okay, this will be a bit of a long set up.

So we are considering:

Suppose $f:E \to \mathbb{C}$ is a branch of the logarithm and that $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $z^n=\exp(nf(z))$.

## My first thoughts

So we are interested in the first place because we have defined the logarithm and our curious to know if it behaves how'd we would like. That is

$$\log(z^n)=n\log(z)$$

So I can't just assume

$$z^n=(\exp(f(z))^N=\exp(nf(z))$$

## My attempt

Consider $n=1$ and we have

$$z=\exp(f(z))$$

Suppose it holds for general $n$ and consider

$$\exp((n+1)f(z))=e^{(n+1)f(z)}=e^{nf(z)}e^{f(z)}=z^{n+1}$$

## My concerns

We have

$$\log(z)=\ln|z|+i\arg(z)$$

So

$$\log(z^n)=\ln|z|^n+i (n\arg(z))$$

How do I know that $(n\arg(z))$ will end up in the right place and not point in a different direction? Is that induction valid (I cannot see why it wouldn't be)?
Finally, isn't

$$z^2=\exp(2f(z))$$

The definition of general complex exponentiation so

$$z^n=\exp(nf(z))$$

by definition?

Thanks for your help and provide as much intuition possible!

Comment: If $n$ is an integer, then $z^n$ is well defined.  Writing $z^n=e^{n\log(z)}=e^{n\log|z|+i(n\arg(z)+2n\ell \pi)}=e^{n\log|z|+in\arg(z)}$.

Comment: So what proof is left to do then?

Comment: Well, $\log(z^n)=n\log|z|+i(n\arg(z)+2\pi n \ell)$ for integer $\ell$ is still multivalued.  What are you trying to prove?

Comment: Not if we take the principal, or any particular branch for that matter.

Comment: Define a branch of the logarithm, let say the principal one for which $-\pi <\arg(z)\le \pi$.  Even then, $\log(e^z)\ne z$ for values of $z$ for which $|\text{Im}(z)|>\pi$.  Suppose $z_1=0$ and $z_2=i2\pi$.  Then $e^{z_1}=e^{z_2}$, and $\log(e^{z_1})=\log(e^{z_2})=0$, but $z_1\ne z_2$.  Similarly, $\log(z_1z_2)$ is not necessarily equal to $\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)$.